# AMD Radeon R5 M330 drivers

Tags: ati, radeon, gpu

Where can I find the drivers for gpu AMD Radeon R5 M330 ? At AMD site there are drivers only for windows.Maybe there is an open source driver or something like a backport?

Answer (score 1):

There is graphics driver for AMD radeon r5 series gpu for notebook (laptop) on there site for ubuntu too. But you have to manually find it by choosing your gpu specific and os type.

But after what I experienced by installing Proprietary driver for AMD radeon r5 230 gpu, I suggest you don't install it. After I installed Proprietary driver in my ubuntu 15.10 on lenovo g40-70, my system entered low graphics mode and showed error with black screen. I had to uninstall driver by entering recovery mode to get it fixed.

There is already open source Xorg driver for AMD radeon gpu. It works fine. If you are facing low battery backup, install tlp and always keep it running. It prevents laptop from overheating and also increases battery backup.  To install it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tlp tlp-rdw
sudo apt-get install tp-smapi-dkms acpi-call-dkms
```

To start it type :sudo tlp start

Also make sure, while running on batter screen brightness is low so that you get more battery backup. After I installed tlp, I always keep it running and thus get backup of around 4 hours for normal use.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running mint 17.3, and the (ubuntu) package fglrx-updates version 2:15.200-0ubuntu0.5 with associated dependecies and recommended packages 
are really working well (as in fabulously well). 
Despite the info on the amd site According to which only r5 m2xx is 
supported), this driver does work for the R5 M330. At least on my laptop.
(hp, i7, r5 m330).

Answer (score 0):

The driver is preinstalled. It is called `radeon` and is the default for most older AMD GPUs. Though I would highly recommend that you use the `padoka` PPA to have access to up-to-date driver components, and to do that, open a terminal and paste these commands into it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:paulo-miguel-dias/mesa
sudo apt-get update
```

After you finish this the next time Software Updater notifies you there are software updates ready to install (which might be instantly after you enter the commands above), it will download and install the updated driver components along with any other available updates if any.

Comment: better be safe than sorry. so maybe `ppa:paulo-miguel-dias/pkppa` for stable builds

Comment: @WillGu I've been using `padoka` for more than 6 months now and I've never passed by any bugs.